# no such file to load -- /app/config/application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a rails app which I've pushed to heroku GIT repo, every thing is fine, until I try to migrate data bases, here is what I get:

```
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ heroku run rake db:migrate --trace
Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.1
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- /app/config/application
/app/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: I've searched for the Rakefile in the whole local project directory, but, I couldn't find it, where it should be ?

Comment: Make sure that you have added all the files to git. 'git add .' then commit again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and figured it out - I'd accidentally added my config folder to my `.gitignore`, so it wasn't pushed to Heroku.

Comment: Although I've fixed it from a long time& I don't remember what I did! as its a one year old question, but I will consider your answer as an answer as its very reasonable explanation :)

Comment: Thanks! Even if it wasn't the reason for your problem, I figured it might help someone else who finds your question.